# The contents of text attachment is Blank when sending mail using sendmail function unix

Tags: unix, sendmail

```
ATTACHMENT=file_list.txt
 smail()
 (
 echo "To: XXXXX@domain.com"
 echo "Subject:abc"
 echo "From: XXXXX@domain.com"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="simple boundary""

 echo "--simple boundary"

 echo "Content-Type: plain/text; name="${ATTACHMENT}""
 echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="${ATTACHMENT}""
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 /usr/bin/base64 ${ATTACHMENT}

 echo "--simple boundary"

 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo ""
 echo "$html_body"
 echo
 echo "--simple boundary--"
 )
 smail | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

The HTML part of the above code is working without any issue. But When I am sending a txt attachment along with with this html content, the contents of the txt attachment is blank.
I have tried including uuencode in place of base64. But unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty line (`echo ""`) after the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have included echo "" and the code is working fine.